# How do I set a minimum value for a decimal in express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to validate my body on a express route and having trouble trying to figure out how to enforce a minimum value for a decimal. I've tried

```
check("price").exists().isDecimal({min:0})
```

and

```
check("price").exists().isDecimal({gt:0})
```

but neither seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using `isFloat(..)`:

```js
console.log(validator.isFloat("7", {min: 5}));
console.log(validator.isFloat("3", {min: 5}));
console.log(validator.isFloat("5.9995", {min: 5}));
console.log(validator.isFloat("1.5", {min: 5}));
console.log(validator.isFloat("-1", {min: 0}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/validator/13.1.0/validator.js"></script>
```